# Pandas convert hex to negative int

Tags: pandas, hex

So, I have a pandas dataframe containing a column of `Hex`, which I'd like to convert to `int`:

```
foo
0xff49f1
0xff49f0
```

The following python code will do each row with the expected results:

```
bar_row_1 = 0xff49f1 - int((0xff49f1 << 1) & 0x1000000)
bar_row_1 = -46607

bar_row_2 = 0xff49f0 - int((0xff49f0 << 1) & 0x1000000)
bar_row_2 = -46608
```

But I'd like to do this for all the rows in my dataframe and output the result in a new column like this:

```
foo      bar
0xff49f1 -46607
0xff49f0 -46608
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
df['bar'] = df['foo'].apply(lambda x: (x - int((x << 1) & 0x1000000)))
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert value to `int` with base `16`:

```
df['bar'] = df['foo'].apply(lambda x: (int(x, 16) - int((int(x, 16) << 1) & 0x1000000)))
print (df)
        foo    bar
0  0xff49f1 -46607
1  0xff49f0 -46608
```